# Cannot import name 'Post' from 'instascrape'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to set up instascraper from this article: https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial/Part%201%20-%20Intro%20to%20the%20API.ipynb

But already when running just this:

```
from instascrape import Post, Profile, Hashtag
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Post' from 'instascrape' (unknown
> location)

How can I fix this?

I've installed the library using

```
pip3 install insta-scrape
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install [insta-scrape](https://pypi.org/project/insta-scrape/), and not a package with a similar name.

```
pip3 install insta-scrape
```

**Update**

Additionally, make sure to uninstall any other packages that may use the same module name, i.e., "instascrape". Most importantly, please make sure you **do not** name your python file, or any other file in the directory your working from **"instascrape.py"**. That might be another reason causing that error.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. I do have the correct package installed.